# Can one schema have multiple users?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a question I wanted to know the exact difference between user and schema?
Can one schema have multiple users, if yes how?

Can someone please explain with good examples.

Comment: That depends on how you interpret the word "have". If you mean "can objects in a single schema be 'owned' by multiple users" the answer is No. If you mean "can objects in a single schema be **used** by multiple users" the answer is most certainly Yes. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 6):

In Oracle user is equivalent to schema. So the answer is no.

Once you create a user eg. scott all objects created by user scott are within his schema. You can access objects from scotts schema by another user like this:

```
select * from scott.emp;
```