# How to assign a user just to one tablespace? - Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

When installing a new db, it is a best practice to create a new user and a new tablespace, because creating tables shouldn't be done with SYS/SYSTEM or/and on the tablespace "SYSTEM".

So I created the user "alex" and the tablespace "alexData" with the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE alexData datafile 'C:/oraclexe/alexData.dbf'
size 100M;
ALTER USER alex QUOTA UNLIMITED ON alexData;
ALTER USER alex QUOTA 0 ON SYSTEM;
```

I want to accomplish that the user "alex" is only able to save his data in the "alexData" tablespace.

Why? Because when he wants to access a table he shouldn't always have to mention the tablespace "alexData".

otherwise he would always need to mention it like:

```
SELECT *
FROM alexData.table
```

but I want that he always is JUST in that tablespace so he doesn't need to mention it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `alexData` in `SELECT * FROM alexData.table` is **not** the tablespace, it's the schema.

Comment: But how can I make alex to save only in the alexData-tablespace? (Because when he creates tables in the SYSTEM-Tablespace, he cannot assign a trigger to those)

Comment: Is he creating them as `CREATE TABLE SYSTEM.MY_TABLE ...`? Because if so, he's not creating them in the SYSTEM **tablespace**, he's creating them in the SYSTEM **schema**, and you'll need to revoke the `CREATE ANY TABLE` privilege from him.

Comment: Ok what do I have to do to resolve a "Cannot create triggers on object owned by SYS"-Exception? Create an own tablespace or an own schema for alex?

Comment: Why do you need to allow user to create triggers on SYS-owned objects? You created production tables under SYS schema? SYS is not intended fo such a usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , Consequence of what @Mat told, you can not use like

`SELECT * FROM alexData.table_` but `SELECT * FROM alex.table_`, since a table may be prefixed with a schema name. As you may notice, you can not use `table`,which is a keyword for oracle, as table name, so i've used `table_` instead.

When you create user, the object is automatically created inside that tablespace. As an example, when `create table ...` statement issued, there's no need to mention about the tablespace provided that you `create` or `alter` your user with `DEFAULT TABLESPACE` phrase:

```
CREATE USER alex IDENTIFIED BY alex321
DEFAULT TABLESPACE alexData
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE alexTempData;
```

*OR*

```
ALTER USER alex IDENTIFIED BY alex321
DEFAULT TABLESPACE alexData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create triggers on a table owned by `SYS`, or `SYSTEM` see:

[Why cannot I create triggers on objects owned by SYS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377346/why-cannot-i-create-triggers-on-objects-owned-by-sys)

If the table on which you wish to create a trigger is a table which you have created, it should live on the `ALEX` schema. This schema should have privileges to create triggers on tables created in the same schema. As previously mentioned in the comments, you should revoke the `CREATE ANY TABLE` privilege from the `ALEX` schema, as this user should only be able to create tables on their own schema.

Comment: I have read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935011/can-one-schema-have-multiple-users?lq=1

That as soon as you create a user, it has its own schema. But in my case, "Alex" is still saving his tables in the "SYSTEM"-Schema

Comment: There is a slightly better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle) to that question - a user and a schema are essentially the same thing. So you should be able to log in as the user `ALEX`, for which you can specify the default tablespace upon creation. Then when you create tables, they will be created in that schema, and using the tablespace you have defined.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to set AlexData as the Default Tablespace!